# How to match lines in one file against lines in another?

Tags: perl, string-matching

I know something is majorly wrong here, but I am new to Perl and looking to do the following:

Find all lines in all.css that contain lines in unused.css and do some logic.  The way my code is structured, it seems that I cannot match something like:

> if ($lineA =~ /$lineU/)  #if line in all.css contains line in unused.css

since the variables are being defined separately.

How would I structure the program to be able to match lines in all.css against lines in unused.css?

My program is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $unused_handle,'<', "unused.css") or die $!;
open(my $all_handle,'<',"all.css") or die $!;
open(my $out, '>' ,'lean.css') or die $!;

my $lineU = q{};
my $lineA = q{};

print $out "$lineU";

while($lineU =<$unused_handle>) {

    print $out "$lineU";
    #print $out "$lineA";  Line One not printed from All
    while($lineA =<$all_handle>) {

        if ($lineA =~ m/$lineU/sxm) {

            print "Huza!\n";
        }

        else {
            print "No Match\n";
        }

    }

}

close ($unused_handle);
close ($all_handle);
close ($out);

print "Done!\n";

exit;
```

An example of my input files is below.

Example lines from unused.css:

```
audio, canvas, video
audio:not([controls])
[hidden]
h6
```

Example lines from all.css:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
audio, canvas, video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}
[hidden] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: `my $infile=<unused.css>;` <-- this doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to define a filename.  What do you recommend?

Comment: open it directly: `open(my $unused_handle,'<', "unused.css") or die $!;` - after that you can use the file handle e.g. `while (my $line=<$unused_handle>)`

Comment: `my $infile="unused.css"; open(my $unused,'<', $infile) or die $!;` However, it's weird to use two different names. I'd go with `my $unused_qfn="unused.css"; open(my $unused_fh,'<', $unused_qfn)`. Using a var for the file name is good cause you can include it in the error message: `die "Can't open $unused_qfn: $!\n";`

Comment: (Don't have time to look if there are other problems)

Comment: What you're doing with `<unused.css>` is asking to iterate over a [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) list of the pattern `unused.css`. Perversely, that will result in a string containing your filename, but it's an abuse of the glob syntax and shouldn't be used. A filename is a simple string: `'unused.css'` is all you need.

Comment: @friedo, It will cause `my $infile2=<all.css>;` to be undef, though. (Second call to `glob` in scalar context for a single-element result)

Comment: I have updated my code to simply open the files directly.  The question remaining is how to use compare lines?

Comment: Is there always a '{' at the end of the relevant lines in all.css?

Comment: Yes, but I don't believe that would not matter since the selector is contained regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this (untested) snippet helps you a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $unused,'<', "unused.css") or die $!;
open(my $all,'<',"all.css") or die $!;

# store all lines of unused.css in a hash
my %unused_line;
while (<$unused>) {
    #remove newlines
    chomp();
    #store the line as a key with empty value
    %unused_line{$_}="";
}
close ($unused);

#...for every line in all.css
while (<$all>) {
    #have we seen it in unused.css (at least everything before ' {')
    if ((m/^(.*\S+)\{/) && (exists $unused_line{$1}))
    {
        #a match - found a line of unused.css in all.css
    }else{
        #no match  - line does not exists in unused.css
    }
}
close ($all);
```

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error with the hash: `%unused_line{$_}="";`

Comment: I am curious as to why you prefer to use a hash over an array here especially since you don't use the key values.

Comment: Ahh it was supposed to be `$unused_line{$_}="";` instead of `%unused_line{$_}="";`

Comment: But unfortunately there are no matches.

Comment: Does the space before the `{` matter?

Comment: Yes, I think this will work. I added a space before the `{` and I have matches!

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah As you see the solution is not very stable, because it depends strictly on the line format (e.g. spaces matter). I prefer a hash here, because you can change the order of the lines, but the whole script is not very elegant. I ask myself if you can't achieve the same effect with `grep` and `sed`, but that might be the topic of another question.

Comment: Yes, it is missing 9 lines somehow, but even so, you have answered my question of how to structure a program to match lines from two files.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if ($lineA =~ m/$lineU/sxm)
```

Also, consider the possibility that you may have differing line endings in the file, and strip line endings prior to performing your comparison.

Finally, I'm hoping that you recognize that you're ignoring the first line of each file by pulling a line prior to starting your while loops.

```
my $lineU = <$unused>;
my $lineA = <$all>;
```

If you didn't want to do this, it would be better to initialize as such:

```
my $lineU = q{};
my $lineA = q{};
```

Comment: Each line in unused.css is exactly contained in all.css since unused.css was extracted from it. I will try this.

Comment: Tried this, still no matches.  I don't think the variables are being evaluated together.  For my understanding, what does 'sxm' mean?

Comment: What did you change exactly?

For the modifiers:
>  m   Treat string as multiple lines.  That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start or end of the string to
           matching the start or end of any line anywhere within the string.

>       s   Treat string as single line.  That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which
           normally it would not match.

>      x   Extend your pattern's legibility by permitting whitespace and comments.  Details in "/x"

Comment: Thank you for your help. +1.  My changes are already viewable in the question.